# GitHub issues character limitation

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying GitHub API and creating new issues and I get the following error:

```
Validation Failed: {"resource":"Issue","code":"custom","field":"body","message":"body is too long"}, {"resource":"Issue","code":"custom","field":"body","message":"body is too long (maximum is 65536 characters)"}
```

Is there a way I can increase this limitation from the GitHub side? Is this even possible?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the API endpoint you're accessing and example of how you're calling it that causes this error?  Right now, we can only guess what's going wrong.